# What are the spawn chances of items from lunchboxes?

Tags: fallout-4

I have found roughly 50 lunchboxes out in the wasteland now and I have noticed the wide variety of things that spawn from them. The occurrence of anything useful seems very low though. Does anyone know the probability of the items that are eligible to spawn from the lunchboxes?

Comment: It seems like it depends on luck, and here's [a list of things you can get](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_lunchbox), but I have yet to see a formula anywhere.

Comment: I'd say about 99% pencils, from my experience

Comment: @CoqPwner: Wow, you're really lucky, free wood and lead. For me it's 99% plastic fork or knife XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_lunchbox), the possible items you can get are:

**Models**

> Mr. Gutsy model
>
> Mr. Handy model
>
> Protectron model
>
> Sentry bot model
>
> Eyebot model

**Aid Items**

> Nuka Cola
>
> Ice cold Nuka Cola
>
> Nuka Cola Quantum
>
> Ice cold Nuka Cola
>
> Quantum Nuka
>
> Cherry Bubblegum
>
> Noodle cup
>
> Gum drops
>
> Dandy Boy Apples

**Junk**

> Plastic fork
>
> Plastic knife
>
> Plastic spoon
>
> Table knife
>
> Dinner fork
>
> Table spoon
>
> Chalk Baseball
>
> Economy wonderglue
>
> Pen Pencil
>
> Wonderglue
>
> Ammo

**Other**

> Fusion core

There does not seem to be a proven formula for drop rate of any of these items, but it is worth noting that you are able to reload a save if you get an undesirable item, in order to try to get a better one.